# What tables hold the job category class and types?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server.

In the table `msdb.dbo.syscategories` how do I get the value for the ids  `category_class` and `category_type` name

i.e: class 1 = JOB
type 1  = LOCAL

Comment: Have you perhaps tried [reading the documentation?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-syscategories-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**You get it from the docs:**](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-syscategories-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

| Column name | Data type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| category_id | int | ID of the category |
| category_class | int | Type of item in the category: |
|  |  | 1 = Job |
|  |  | 2 = Alert |
|  |  | 3 = Operator |
| category_type | tinyint | Type of category: |
|  |  | 1 = Local |
|  |  | 2 = Multiserver |
|  |  | 3 = None |
| name | sysname | Name of the category |

The system catalog views typically don't have "lookup tables" for each of these.